# How to find emprical PDF by using the normalized histogram?

Tags: probability, density-function, histogram, function

first of all, thank you for your time, here is my question;

*Is it possible to find emprical PDF by using normalized histogram?*

I am trying to learn discrete event simulation and what I see is there is lots of statistical models which I am not so much familiar with. More specificly;

I have data points such as ; 
26.5    74.1    80.3    72.3    87.7    60.9    98.3    52.1    40.8   74.3    13.4    92.5    79.2    74.1    84.1    42.6    57.3    65.4   66.5    72.5    55.2    33.2    79.2    33.9    18.4    83.6    10.4   56.3    82.5    99.8    49.9    19.6    68.3    45.4    59.9    16.8

And I find histogram like this

[image: Histogram]

From there, what I really want is find the emprical PDF by using histogram that I obtained and make a graph like this;

[image]

Please note that, this is not a homework or something like that and also I actually solving and constructing histogram by hand. After that When I find this PDF, I will compare mean and variance by using it. I am assuming that I have to look to the histogram and make an assumption maybe?

Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

If you standardize your histogram, you get a probability density function. In your case, this pdf will be a very poor approximation of the real pdf that rendered the process you measured, since you got only 36 data points. Having so few data, I would only compute the median and the mean of the data.
Since your data are numerical, I wouldn't fit any model with less than 100 data points.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I know data is not enough but I was just warming myself on concept.